# Heap Corruption Detected after normal block #63

Tags: c

So, I have this simple code that initializes a matrix of integers from user,and sorts the array in various ways and uses dynamic memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void initArrays();
void printArr(int** matrix, int rows);
void sortArr(int** matrix,int rows);
void printByOrder(int** matrix,int rows);
int main(void)
{
    initArrays();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void initArrays()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int * arr = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int** matrix = 0;
    int rows = 0;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    matrix = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter array length for row %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &len);
        arr = (int*)malloc(len * sizeof(int));
        arr[0] = len;
        for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
        {
            printf("Enter value for array: ");
            scanf("%d",arr + j + 1);
        }   
        matrix[i] = arr;
    }
    printArr(matrix, rows);
    sortArr(matrix,rows);
    printByOrder(matrix, rows);
    free(matrix);
    free(arr);

}

void printArr(int** matrix, int rows)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    printf("Printing:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= matrix[i][0];j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }





}
void sortArr(int ** matrix, int rows)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int* arr = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int swap = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) //getting a single arr to work with.
    {
        arr = matrix[i];

        for (j = 1; j < arr[0]; j++)
        {
            pos = j;

            for (k = j + 1; k <= arr[0]; k++) //selection sort.
            {
                if (arr[pos] > arr[k])
                {
                    pos = k;
                }

            }
            if (pos != j)
            {
                swap = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[pos];
                arr[pos] = swap;
            }
        }

    }
        matrix[i] = arr;

        printf("Sorted Rows: \n");
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < matrix[i][0] + 1; j++)
            {
                printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }


}

void printByOrder(int** matrix, int rows)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int smallest = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int* swap = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < rows - 1; j++)
    {
        pos = j;

        for (i = j + 1; i < rows; i++) //selection sort.
        {
            if (matrix[pos][0] > matrix[i][0])
            {
                pos = i;
            }

        }
        if (pos != j)
        {
            swap = matrix[j];
            matrix[j] = matrix[pos];
            matrix[pos] = swap;
        }

    }
    printf("Ordered Array: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < matrix[i][0] + 1; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }


        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

My only problem is that when the `free` function comes in, the program crashes with the error "Heap Corruption Detected after normal block #63".I have tried running the program without the `free` and it worked fine.
I tried searching around, and I couldn't find why this error was occurring to me. Could anyone explain it to me?
Thanks!

Comment: This `matrix = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int));` should be `matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));` or even less error-prone `matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof *matrix);`

Comment: Also just drop all those useless casts, and make all `int`s `size_t` or at least `unsigned`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind (see http://valgrind.org/) shows the problem in your:

```
scanf("%d",arr + j + 1);
```

line.

If you want to keep the length on the first position your allocation size:

```
arr = (int*)malloc(len * sizeof(int));
```

is too small (you need one more `int` for the length itself).

Comment: The thing is that arr[0] represents the arr len entered. Since I star j from 0 i give it 1 everytime

Comment: @MichaelFel123: But then for `j== row` `arr` is accessed out of bounds, invoking UB.

Comment: If you want to keep the length as the first member your malloc(len * sizeof(int)) is incorrect, as you need one more entry for the length itself, otherwise, as @alk pointed out, you will write beyond the end of your allocated block.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to free a makeshift matrix like what you've created, you iterate through the pointed-to array and free each of those pointers, and then free the main pointer. Do not free `arr`, as this points to the last created array. Something like this should work nicely for you:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    free(matrix[i]);
}

free(matrix);
```

Comment: I am going to try it. Didn't have time